# Getting CORS error when trying to read JSON data from my own localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I have a node ('test.js') script that outputs JSON data to the screen. I compile and run it, and when I open the site in my browser http://localhost:3000/myWorkspace/Projects/MW-KD/ I can see the json data {'kills':22,'deaths':11,'map':'someMap','kdRatio':2.........} on the screen.

Now I want to read this data from another javascript file using $.ajax. I tried everything btw. ($.get(), $.post(), $.getJSON, fetch() etc)

The code I use is:

```
let settings = {
  'cache': false,
  'dataType': "json",
  'async': true,
  'crossDomain': true,
  'url": "http://localhost:3000/myWorkspace/Projects/MW-KD/',
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
  }
}

let testJSON = $.ajax(settings)
testJSON.done((data) => console.log(data))
```

I tried like every single combination people use but still I get a f.... CORS error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/myWorkspace/Projects/MW-KD/?_=1587570791195' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This CORS error is haunting me for days now. I got em when using Activisions API. I got 'em when using javascript. Then I thought I could use a 3rd party API using NODE. So I installed and looked up the basics. I got the API to run and return me results form Activisions API.

AND NOW I CANT READ THE DATA ON MY OWN MACHINE. I'm about to lose my mind.

Comment: You don't control CORS from the client side; that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: I'm a coding noob. I don't even know what CORS is.

Comment: Then you might want to do this now -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing (or just search for _"CORS"_ here on SO)

Comment: That might be worth looking up then :)

Comment: So I need to set the http header in the server-side script to allow the communication?

Comment: Yes, set ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin``` to ```*``` on your server-side.

Comment: Don't use `*` just because it's easier. Only allow your own domain(s) to access the resources.